Oracle Database Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" / "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following
I've just started with Oracle Database XE, and I'm struggling with 2 errors in my code:
Error(89,5): PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "EXCEPTION" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:     ( begin case declare else elsif end exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge standard pipe purge json_object
Error(95): PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "end-of-file" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:     end not pragma final instantiable persistable order    overriding static member constructor map

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE registrar_devolucion (p_alquilerID IN Alquileres_eco.ID%TYPE, p_fechadev IN DATE)
AS 

v_fecha_ini  ALQUILERES_ECO.FECHAINI%TYPE;
v_dias_alq NUMBER;
v_precioxdia NUMBER;
v_precio_alq NUMBER;
v_descuento NUMBER;
v_ecopuntos NUMBER;
v_dni_cliente CLIENTES_ECO.DNI%TYPE;
v_nombre_cliente CLIENTES_ECO.NOMBRE%TYPE;
v_matricula MOTOS_ECO.MATRICULA%TYPE;
v_modelo MOTOS_ECO.MODELO%TYPE;

BEGIN 

    -- Comprobamos que el alquiler existe
    SELECT dni, Matricula
    INTO v_dni_cliente, v_matricula
    FROM Alquileres_eco
    WHERE AlquilerID = p_alquilerID;



    --Calculamos los dias de alquiler

v_dias_alq := p_fechadev - v_fecha_ini;

    --Act DiasAlquiler y confirmar

    UPDATE Alquileres_eco
    SET FechaFin = p_fechadev,
      DiasAlquiler = v_dias_alq
    WHERE AlquilerID = p_alquilerID;


    --Verificar si la fecha de devolucion es anterior a la de inicio

IF v_fechadev < v_fecha_ini THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'la devolución del Alquiler con ID:' || p_AlquilerID || 'tiene una fecha de devolución: ' || p_fechadev || 'anterior a la fecha de inicio de alquiler.');

    --Calc descuento

v_descuento := ALQUILERES_ECO.DESCUENTO;


    -- Calcular precio del alquiler
    SELECT PrecioPorDia, Descuento
    INTO v_precioxdia, v_descuento
    FROM Motos_eco
    WHERE Matricula = v_matricula;


v_precio_alq := (v_precioxdia * v_dias_alq) * v_descuento/ 100 ;


    --Act PrecioAlquiler y confirmar

    UPDATE Alquileres_eco
    SET PrecioAlquiler = v_precio_alq
    WHERE AlquilerID = P_alquilerID;

    -- Actualizar disponibilidad y confirmamos
    UPDATE Motos_eco
    SET Disponible = 'SI'
    WHERE Matricula = v_matricula;
    SELECT Modelo 
    INTO v_modelo 
    FROM motos_eco 
    WHERE Matricula = v_matricula;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('La moto de matrícula: ' || v_matricula || ' y modelo: ' || v_modelo || ' ahora está disponible');


    --Ecopuntos del cliente y actualizar

v_ecopuntos := TRUNC(v_precio_alq/10);

    UPDATE Clientes_eco
    SET EcoPuntos = EcoPuntos + v_ecopuntos
    WHERE DNI = v_dni_cliente;

    --Obtener nombre del cliente y actualizamos sus puntos

    SELECT Nombre INTO v_nombre_cliente FROM Clientes_eco WHERE Dni = v_dni_cliente;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El cliente con DNI: ' || v_dni_cliente || ' y nombre: ' || v_nombrecliente_ || ' tiene un total de ' || EcoPuntos || ' puntos');

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'El Alquiler con ID: ' || p_alquilerID || ' no existe.');
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'Error inesperado al registrar la devolución para el Alquiler con ID: ' || p_alquilerID);
END;
/


I really don't know what could be wrong, I've checked it a thousand times and I can't find the error.

You have IF .. THEN but no END IF.

You also appear to use v_fecha_ini before assigning a value to it. And v_descuento := ALQUILERES_ECO.DESCUENTO; does not look valid (but I don't know what you are trying to do to make a suggestion on what could be correct).

Your IF statement miss its END IF.
